# pull to refresh not refreshing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am attempting to implement pull to refresh in a fragment of an android app. When I pull the fragment view, the refresh icon appears but the view is never refreshed.
Here is my attempt in the xml file>>>

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ....

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Here in my fragment view I have below code to implement what I have done in the xml file

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        final SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);

        pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, 5000);

            }
        });



        return v;
    }
```

on launching the application and dragging to pull to refresh nothing happens despite that the refresh icons appears.

Comment: Where is your code to refresh your Fragment? You need to do something, the Fragment doesn't automagically refresh itself. At the moment you just display the refresh animation, that why... it just displays the refresh animation. Base on what you try to refresh, you probably need to do a call to an API or something like that.

Comment: I dont have any other code except what I have provided. And that is my challenge at the moment

Comment: So yeah, you need to write a code to refresh the data, in the `onRefresh()`. At the moment you just delay end the animation, that's why this is all you have.

Comment: You delayed the code with 5 seconds . Did it not called after 5 second ?

Comment: @ADM no it did not

Comment: After 5 second refresh should stop . Although I have no idea what you trying to accomplish .

Comment: @ADM There is no code called after 5s, except the one stopping the animation. Which is the current behaviour OP has at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically:

```
 @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // Do async call or whatever to get the new data
        // Update your data e.g:
        //    - RecylerView: update the data in your adapter and call 'notifyDataSetChanged'
        //    - fixed views: update the field
        // Call `pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);`
    }
```

**EDIT**

How to call `pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false)`, for it to always be called at the correct time (means when all the data have really been refreshed):

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    update();
}

private void update(){
    // Get the data synchronously or asynchronously
    // update the view with the data
    // then: (remove the code relative to the Handler)
    pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Comment: I simply added the function that needed to be called in the on refresh method and that was it... Thanks

Comment: Don't delay the call to `pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);` you should call it when all the data has been updated. So if it's synchronous, this should be at the end of the function, if it's asynchronous it should be at the end of all the operation of the async call. At the moment it's called after 5s but depending on your implement it can take more or less time for the data to be refreshed.

Comment: You mean I should comment it out >>>> pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

Answer (score 0):

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

```
    final SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);

    final ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv);
    new (xxx lv).execute();

    pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            **You have to write code that you need to perform on refresh calling**
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 5000);

        }
    });



    return v;
}
```

Except code for calling function that need to work on refresh is not there.

Comment: You don't need to manually delay `pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false)` as it should be called when all the data have been refreshed and not after a specific time.

Comment: I understand that, but i think its questioner requirement. So i did that.